# use UIHint on a double to display it as per US culture

Tags: c#

Can you use UIHint to customise a textbox in mvc to always display numeric values as per en US culture, regardless of user local (browser) settings? Any pointers to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can either create a new Editor or Display Template and reference it with `UIHint` or you overwrite the `Double.cshtml` templates.

For example, create `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Double.cshtml` with the following content:

```
@* Editor for double property in fixed format *@
@model double?

@using System.Globalization;

@{
    /* for standard template see http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html */

    object modelValue;
    if (Model == null) {
        modelValue = ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText;
    }
    else {
        // US format, two decimal places, no thousands seperators
        modelValue = new HtmlString(string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:f2}", Model));   
    }
}

<div class=""> @* set correct classes here depending on your CSS framework *@
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m)
    @Html.TextBox("", modelValue, Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("", Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata))
</div>
```

Inserting the right HTML attributes based on ViewModel attributes ("required" etc.) can be done by inspecting the `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. The code above only shows a minimal example for unobtrusive validation attributes.

Watch out, setting `type="number"` and `step="any"` can interfere with validation that a point '.' must be used for decimal places!